# Getting the right font for text in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm using the following commands in my preamble to get the fonts I want:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
```

I recently found that, in math mode, when I use the command `\log` or `\exp` (as opposed to `\text{log}` or `\text{exp}`), the logarithmic and exponential functions get resolved in the math font I want to use (pxfonts). However, I often use other functions such as "logit" and "expit", for example:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{logit} \Bigg \{ P(Y = 1| X = x) \Bigg \} = \beta_0 + s(x), 
\end{equation}
```

In this case, "logit" resolves in the font used in the main text (cmbright), which stands out as somewhat of an eyesore. Is there a way I can create functions `\logit` and `\expit` that, in math mode, will return "logit" and "expit" using the desired math font (pxfonts) and not the main text font (cmbright)?

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` (from `amsmath`) is your friend.

Comment: Not related directly to your question, but hopefully still useful: Instead of `\Bigg \{ P(Y = 1| X = x) \Bigg \}`, you may want to write `\bigl\{\, P(Y = 1\mid X = x) \,\bigr\}`. If you *really* need the curly braces to be bigger than `\big`, try `\Big` -- but not `\Bigg`.

Comment: @Mico: Cool. Thanks for the tip. I'll see how it turns out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath`; this will also give you the right spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\logit}{logit}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\text{logit} \Bigg \{ P(Y = 1| X = x) \Bigg \} = \beta_0 + s(x)\\
\logit \Bigg \{ P(Y = 1| X = x) \Bigg \} = \beta_0 + s(x)
\end{gather} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A cleaner solution might be to use `\mathrm{logit}`.